# DataAnnotations in .NET Question

Tags: .net, validation, data-annotations

Hi
Just a fast question.
I am trying to use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations in .NET to do my validations.
so on the properties, I will add the attributes that validation the property.
And I will do that on the Business Domain Model
My question is:
I know the behavior when you use validation from dataannotations, that when you set up a property with invalid data, will throw exception.
Can I change that, and set all the properties, and then call something to validate the data, and the validation gives me all the  errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataAnnotations is not an AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) system, that will inject checks in your code for you. With DataAnnotations you annotate your model and setting a property to an invalid value will not do anything; it will *not* throw an exception. You will have to call the validate method yourself. In other words, the default model with DataAnotations is that you can set multiple properties of an entity with (invalid) values and validate them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Policy Injection Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664572%28PandP.50%29.aspx) from Microsoft Enterprise Library with the Validation handler to accomplish that. Notice, the handler will call into the [Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664356%28PandP.50%29.aspx) which [respects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664638%28PandP.50%29.aspx) all DataAnnotations attributes. It also offers you additional comprehensive validation capabilities (including composite validations and validation rulesets).